# Template constraints in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b){
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value 
                 || std::is_floating_point<T>::value
                 , "Not a numeric value");
    return a + b;
}
```

Are there other/better ways to enforce constraints on templates?

Comment: At compile time? What kind of data are you dealing with (how can it vary?) This is a broad question and kind of subjective too

Comment: You could use enable_if

Comment: It depends on what you want to happen when an invalid type is passed. Given a class `C` with a conversion `operator int()` and an instance `c`, do you want `add(c, c)` to be an error, or should it be okay because `C` should be implicitly converted to the only possible numeric type?

Comment: You can look into [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and/or [Boost.ConceptCheck](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm)

Comment: enable_if makes only the template invisible for non accepted types. This will result in a bad error message of the compiler. So I prefer static_assert in this case.

Comment: What's your use case?  This function you've written looks a lot like `std::plus<>`, so could you just use that?  It doesn't seem very necessary to check the types--if you can "plus" them then do it.  Unless your point is to avoid "adding" std::string in which case you could use enable_if.

Comment: @Angew That's it, I saw this in the past but I could not remember how it looked.

Comment: `enable_if` uses SFINAE and should be used when you have another overload candidate, from a correctness point of view the `static_assert` sounds better since I suppose you're trying to verify the correctness of your input without any alternative

Comment: @hvd It would be nice if add(c,c) would result in an error. I didn't even think about type conversions.

Comment: Also, use `is_arithmetic` which combines `is_integral` and `is_floating_point` already.

Comment: You could always wait until the next C++ standard ([supposedly C++17](https://isocpp.org/std/status)) when [concepts](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s) hopefully finally will be in the standard.

Comment: @Maik > It would be nice if `add(c,c)` would result in an error. `#include<stdexcept> template<typename T> auto add(T&& a, T&& b) ->decltype(a+b) {if(&a==&b) throw std::invalid_argument(); else return a+b;}` or `#include<cassert> template<typename T> auto add(T&& a, T&& b) ->decltype(a+b) {assert(&a!=&b); return a+b;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static_assert` as you used will give the compiler error you specified if someone tries to invoke the template with an inappropriate type.

`enable_if` is an alternative, but will give an error that the template is not defined. This may well confuse a user who thinks it is defined, and would have to look at more detail.

Assuming you want

1. The compilation to fail if an incorrect type is used (unless the user has written a specialization for their own type)
2. The error given will be meaningful.

What you outlined above with `static_assert` seems a good way of achieving this.

Of course you have given us a very simple template and I am sure you are likely to be considering a more complex one.

Comment: You can also combine both approaches with one specialization behaving as usual and the other failing with static_assert

Answer (score 1):

Why you're doing this? You can do it in Duck-Typing style: you don't check if the types fits, if there is no `operator+` defined it simply doesn't compile.

```
#define RETURNS(WHAT) ->decltype(WHAT) {return WHAT;}
template<typename T>
auto add(T a, T b) RETURNS(a+b)
```

Comment: I believe OP has more complex template system in mind